# The client certificate is NULL - Sandbox Integration

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api

I'm following the guide to [delete a customer account from the integration sandbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/partnercenter/mt414178.aspx) but when I send the following request:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://api.cp.microsoft.com/d3bc3d3b-ace9-463a-923c-1bd05679eed8/customers/delete-tip-reseller-customer?=' \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.hgwKCe0vMwqsZ2D7KIG1m5O_x86pjgp527BCIGZJTrl_fUS0Ei0qS8dwHAX0BfBp3dt5XtMCW-yXFXRCOuLPr4Sd1Wlq5_U_bdSOaCAM_DxmVUuZX2_DnbLNnL04P2-An-puuy3iURIyKiUYBts5IIl3DpwigSe0ksFfQc2DwnOuPdMBH6leQ0Qa7P2TSuhmuQGntEmjDsoshS0y2DTqzGhksMuJnW5j7YWCf7BRIK0PSCpecFpgLzLt_BwEh4UDEE8b_HQCzoFv00GiRf_OAwcnpcoHNjRz-LLGkKBVbga6m8vuitGyXyR28rzNLsh7Oh7iY8Wd7VXMgYIv_hIo4w' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{\n   "customer_id": "f92732de-4a6a-4e34-a5da-f57bb607764b"\n}'
```

I got this error which is unexplained on the internet:

```
{
    "code": "HttpStatusCodeForbidden",
    "error_code": "HttpStatusCodeForbidden",
    "message": "The client certificate is NULL.",
    "object_type": "Error"
}
```

I don't know what's wrong with the request or the SA Token, my other requests work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the documentation from Microsoft is not up to date. I followed [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/partnercenter/mt712728.aspx) to delete a customer from the integration sandbox. I send the following request and the client was removed :

```
curl --request DELETE \
  --url https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/customers/f92732de-4a6a-4e34-a5da-f57bb607764b \
  --header 'accept: application/json' \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.hgwKCe0vMwqsZ2D7KIG1m5O_x86pjgp527BCIGZJTrl_fUS0Ei0qS8dwHAX0BfBp3dt5XtMCW-yXFXRCOuLPr4Sd1Wlq5_U_bdSOaCAM_DxmVUuZX2_DnbLNnL04P2-An-puuy3iURIyKiUYBts5IIl3DpwigSe0ksFfQc2DwnOuPdMBH6leQ0Qa7P2TSuhmuQGntEmjDsoshS0y2DTqzGhksMuJnW5j7YWCf7BRIK0PSCpecFpgLzLt_BwEh4UDEE8b_HQCzoFv00GiRf_OAwcnpcoHNjRz-LLGkKBVbga6m8vuitGyXyR28rzNLsh7Oh7iY8Wd7VXMgYIv_hIo4w' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json'
```